# SQL convert a row into two columns (label-value)

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot, unpivot

I query my database and get the following row:

```
**NAME | DESCRIPTION | MOBILE | EMAIL | CENTER |**

George | Nice guy    | 644213568 | geo@gmail.com | NASA |
```

---

I'd like to convert it into:

**LABEL | VALUE**

```
Name | George

DESCRIPTION | Nice guy

MOBILE | 644213568

EMAIL | geo@gmail.com

CENTER | NASA
```

---

Thank you in advance!!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want `apply` :

```
select tt.LABEL, tt.VALUE
from table t cross apply
     ( values ('DESCRIPTION', DESCRIPTION), ('MOBILE', MOBILE), ('EMAIL', EMAIL), ('CENTER', CENTER) 
     ) tt(LABEL, VALUE)
 where t.USER_ID = 23;
```

Comment: thanks, it works! but what about if I want to add a where clause? I mean, table **t** has many rows, I just want one row, as if my row was given from SELECT ... FROM T WHERE USER_ID = 23,,, thanks!

Comment: @mantc_sdr. . . You can use `WHERE` clause after `CROSS APPLY`.

Comment: You can use something like   select tt.LABEL, tt.VALUE
from [table] t   cross apply
     ( values ('DESCRIPTION', DESCRIPTION)
     ) tt(LABEL, VALUE) where t.id=1;